# tikzmark, listings and beamer's onlyenv

Tags: beamer, listings, tikzmark

I found this limitation in the current `tikzmark` solution for highlighting lines of `listings` code in `beamer`. When I put the whole lot in an `onlyenv` environment, it seems the marks are not set, or found. Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit}
\usetikzmarklibrary{listings}
\newcommand{\showmark}[2]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\draw[red,thick] ({pic cs:line-#1-#2-first}) -- ({pic cs:line-#1-#2-end});}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{onlyenv}<1>
\showmark{first}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}[name=first]
Listing
In first slide
\end{lstlisting}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<2>
\showmark{second}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}[name=second]
Listing
In second slide
\end{lstlisting}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I see a red line in the first slide, but not in the second. Is there any (simple) workaround for this problem? Or am I doing something wrong?

PS. The `\showmark` macro is just a quick way of showing the problem.

Comment: Did you run it twice?

Comment: @PeterGrill Many more times than two, actually. Does it work for you? It could mean I need to update some packages in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you don't restart the value for the lines, the second line in the second listing is actually the fourth line; either restart the lines or use the proper value:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit}
\usetikzmarklibrary{listings}
\newcommand{\showmark}[2]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\draw[red,thick] ({pic cs:line-#1-#2-first}) -- ({pic cs:line-#1-#2-end});}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{onlyenv}<1>
\showmark{aaa}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}[name=aaa]
Listing
In first slide
\end{lstlisting}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<2>
\showmark{second}{4}
\begin{lstlisting}[name=second]
Listing
In second slide
\end{lstlisting}

\end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Under normal conditions, using `\resetcounteronoverlays` (or `\resetcountonoverlays` for a TeX counter) would take care of preventing a counter from stepping on overlays; however, when the `name=<name>` option is used for a listing, the values for the line numbers are stored inside `\lstno@<name>` which is a *macro* and not a counter, so `\resetbeameronoverlays` will not work and there's no native way to prevent the undesired behaviour. One can manually set the counter to the appropriate value, or set explicitly the appropriate number for `firstnumber`, as shown below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit}
\usetikzmarklibrary{listings}
\newcommand{\showmark}[2]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\draw[red,thick] ({pic cs:line-#1-#2-first}) -- ({pic cs:line-#1-#2-end});}%
}

\resetcounteronoverlays{lstnumber}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{onlyenv}<1>
\showmark{first}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}[name=first]
Listing
In first slide
\end{lstlisting}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<2>
\showmark{second}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}[name=second,firstnumber=1]
Listing
In second slide
\end{lstlisting}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit}
\usetikzmarklibrary{listings}
\newcommand{\showmark}[2]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\draw[red,thick] ({pic cs:line-#1-#2-first}) -- ({pic cs:line-#1-#2-end});}%
}

\resetcounteronoverlays{lstnumber}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{onlyenv}<1>
\showmark{first}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}[name=first]
Listing
In first slide
\end{lstlisting}
\end{onlyenv}
\makeatletter
\def\lstno@second{1}
makeatother
\begin{onlyenv}<2>
\showmark{second}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}[name=second]
Listing
In second slide
\end{lstlisting}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Related to this problem is [Problem with listings when using line numbers, `name`, and `beamer` overlays](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164932/3954). I initially though about manually resetting `\lst@firstnumber`, but as **Andrew Swann** explains in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165130/3954), it's better to consider `\lstno@<name>`.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I tried resetting the line numbers, because that would make each piece of code more self-contained. But when I add `firstnumber=1` to both `lstlisting` options, I get the opposite behavior: red line in the second slide and not in the first. Besides, the manual seems to imply that by using the `name` option the lines start at 1... Could you provide an example resetting the line numbers?

Comment: @Jellby unfortunately, the native `beamer` solution (`\resetcounteronoverlays`) won't work when `name` is used (the reason is included in my edited answer), so there's no "natural way to prevent the undesired behaviour". I provided a work-around in my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, and do you know why adding `firstnumber=1` to the first listing doesn't work? It works for all of them, even in other frames, except for the first (at least in my tests).

Comment: @Jellby I also noticed that. I didn't dig enough into the code of `listings`, so I don't know the reason.

Comment: @Jellby I updated my answer with new information that might be of interest for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. However, it doesn't work if the overlay specification are out of order (try with `<1>` first, then `<3>`, and then `<2>`). This may be needed, for example, when using the `onlyenv` inside a `columns` environment: The left column may contain `<1-2>` and `<3>`, and the right column `<2>`.