# Problem with listings when using line numbers, `name`, and `beamer` overlays

Tags: beamer, listings, counters

It's is well known that to ensure that a certain `<counter>` is automatically reset on subsequent slides of a same frame one has to use either `\resetcounteronoverlays{<counter>}` (for LaTeX counters) or `\resetcountonoverlays{<counter>}` (for TeX counters). However, this seems not to work for the `lstnumber` counter used for numbering lines in a `lstlisting` environment when the `name` key is used, as the following simple MWE shows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{numbers=left}
\resetcounteronoverlays{lstnumber}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{onlyenv}<1>
\begin{lstlisting}[name=first]
test line in first listing
\end{lstlisting}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<2>
\begin{lstlisting}[name=second]
test line in second listing
\end{lstlisting}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

If the `name` option is not used, the effect of `\resetcounteronoverlays{lstnumber}` is the expected and one gets the correct result.

How can the `lstnumber` be prevented from stepping when using the `name` key and `beamer` overlays?

Comment: This gets better if you give the two listings the same name...the second then has line number `4`!  When `name=first` the starting number is stored in the macro, not counter, `\lstno@first`.  There is no standard `beamer` command to rest that.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks. I think the macro is `\lst@firstnumber`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina That is cerntainly involved too, and gets updated by `\lst@SetFirstNumber` which uses `\lstno@first`

Comment: @AndrewSwann would you like to provide an answer based on your comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For named listings, with say `name=myprog`, the values of line numbers is kept track of in corresponding macros `\lstno@myprog`.  Unfortunately they are indeed macros and not counters, so the usual beamer resetting commands have no effect.  On an individual listing you can always provide the `firstnumber` option to specify the starting line number.  Otherwise, you need to do some manual resetting of the macros `\lstno@...` etc.

In the following we reset the numbering for the second family of listings in these two different ways.  This gives

First overlay: `name=first`, OK

[image: Sample one]

Second overlay: `name=second`, line number set explicitly, OK

[image: Sample two]

Second slide, first overlay: `name=first`, no resetting, goes wrong

[image: Sample three]

Second slide, second overlay: `name=second`, reset before frame, OK

[image: Sample four]

The resetting can also be done between overlays within a frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{numbers=left}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{onlyenv}<1>
\begin{lstlisting}[name=first]
test line in first listing
\end{lstlisting}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<2>
\begin{lstlisting}[name=second,firstnumber=1]
test line in second listing
\end{lstlisting}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}

\makeatletter
\def\lstno@second{1}
\makeatother

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{onlyenv}<1>
\begin{lstlisting}[name=first]
test line in first listing
\end{lstlisting}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<2>
\begin{lstlisting}[name=second]
test line in second listing
\end{lstlisting}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that setting `\lst@firstnumber` is not the correct thing to do, that sets the starting number for all listings.